# Using the Profile2 module, how to access contextual information to place a views block on profile page?

Tags: views, users

I'm trying to add a list of author's content to a profile2 page. The profile page is separate from the user account page so I can't use get UID from URL option.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [View Default Argument From Context](http://drupal.org/project/views_arg_context) Module I added this code to it.

```
function views_arg_context_profile2_view($entity, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  context_set('user', 'uid', $entity->uid);
  context_set('profile', 'pid', $entity->pid);
}
```

Now there is an option in Views Default Argument to pull the ID from context and I place either user or profile in the appropriate text field and it works fine.

Comment: could you explain this further how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this module: http://drupal.org/project/eva. It sounds like using tokens you could probably achieve what you are needing.

I think you could also use page manager/[panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to override the profile page and load a context with the author id and pass the context to a view content pane. This probably has a little more overhead and learning curve involved if you are not familiar with panels.

Comment: Entity Views Attach would work except that it adds the information to a field that is attached to the entity -- it doesn't create a separate block.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the profile2 page or have access to the `$profile2` object, you can access it's owner by looking at `$profile2->uid`

Comment: It's not an option in the Views UI. I use hook_entity_view to set the variable in the Context object using Context's setter. This way Views has a way to get at it.